# Populate planet with data

Tags: coordinate-system, tiles

i have a game that described a planet and is a sphere.

on the client side, the world is separated to tiles (images) and i mapped it follow by [this](http://jvalentino.blogspot.com/2010/09/building-custom-2d-map-component-in-any.html) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx), so now when the user is zooming / dragging the world he's see the right location follow by the middle-center geo coordinate and global pixel.

now, on my server side, i need to put data on my planet (in other words, to draw it on the tiles i mentioned above - but it's doesn't matter for this discussion).

i have array of data items with same dimensions (width/height) that should be populate on the planet.
from my own understanding, i need to find the geo coordinate of each data-item and then use the function geoToGlobalPX() to get it's location against the whole 2d planet's map, and finally 'put' it on the planet.

my problem is to find this geo coordinate, since i can't run over the planet from pixel(0, 0) to pixel(PLANET_SIZE, PLANET_SIZE) and each iteration grow the current-position in item-data-width because the range of location is decreasing as much you're going up/down from the equator, so on the top latitude (~85) i'll have more less data-items than on the equator.

i tried to read on the articles above about meters-per-pixel but i still don't really understood how i can integrate it on my system.

i hope you understood my and someone will have some advice for me.

thanks.

Shlomi.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to render 2D tiles to a 3D globe?.

I would look into **XNavigator** is an interactive 3D viewer and integrated client for exploring virtual city and landscape model

http://koenigstuhl.geog.uni-heidelberg.de/xnaviwiki/doku.php

Open Street Map are using this to render their tiles on the globe and in 3D (zoomed in)

Have a look at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM-3D
it might be a good starting point for your application.

They are using **B64**

> Context document encoded in Base64
>   binary format. The context describes
>   the client configuration, including
>   definition and selection of layers,
>   service URLs (W3DS, Geocoder, Route
>   Service, WMS, EQS etc.), definition of
>   viewpoint parameters, navigation mode,
>   lighting settings, and much more. The
>   context can be created using the
>   XNavigator Webstart, Create Applet
>   menu.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM-3D_Applet

[image]